# How to Name OurCustomerNumber and TheirCustomerNumber

Tags: database-design

All business partners are stored in one table and can be customers, suppliers or both. Now I need to store the customer number the business partner has assigend to our company ("their customer number for us") as well as the customer number our company has assigend to the business partner ("our customer number for them").

What is an elegant way to name these columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting your existing Table with some sample data would help clarify things. Can both numbers exist for the same record in this Table?...if so then having two columns with the names you already picked are fine. Or you can use `InternalCustomerNunber` (being the one you guys assigned them) and `ExternalCustomerNumber` (being the one they assigned).

I'm a fan of column names that clearly describe what they represent, even if it's verbose and/or not elegant. Readability is more important.

Otherwise if a record can only have one or the other, you should use a generic field called `CustomerNumber` with a separate boolean type column called `IsCustomerNumberInternal` (or `IsOurCustomerNumber`) as a way to differentiate which one it is. This follows the *one field one purpose* principle.